# install-package Thinktecture.IdentityServer3 command gives error in visual studio package manager console?

Tags: oauth-2.0, thinktecture-ident-server, thinktecture

When i run following command in package manager console:

```
install-package Thinktecture.IdentityServer3
```

I am getting error:

> Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Thinktecture.IdentityServer3'
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + install-package <<<<  Thinktecture.IdentityServer3
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

I am following this tutorial to secure my restful api- https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/overview/simplestOAuth.html

and using visual studio 2015 express for web.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `install-package IdentityServer3`

Check the latest tutorial here https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html

Comment: Yeah, they dropped the Thinktecture prefix mid 2015. The documentation you are looking at for 1.x, latest tutorial for OAuth is: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/simplestOAuth.html